# Problem parsing the body of a POST request

Tags: php

So what I'm trying to do is: with a link similar to: [http://localhost/API-REST/Endpoints/ajoutDeMessage.php?contenu='Hello'&idUser=4](http://localhost/API-REST/Endpoints/ajoutDeMessage.php?contenu=%27Hello%27&idUser=4). For now, I'm only testing my request with Postman. So I'm putting this URL directly in Postman, and press send.

When I'm doing a request without a body, it works fine.

So, I need to send a string and an id through the URL, and with a function, I'm inserting these data in my database.

With the `php://input`, I expect to have the variables `contenu` and `idUser` in the body for a SQL request.

What I want to do next is a React app which will communicate with the API (but that's not related for now).

So here is my code:

```php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    require_once('../Configuration/database.php');
    require_once('../Users/messages.php');

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->getConnection();

    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
    var_dump($json);
    
    if(!empty($json->contenu) && !empty($json->idUser)){
        $contenu = strip_tags($json->contenu);
        $idUser = strip_tags($json->idUser);

        $message = new Messages($db);
        if ($message->addMessage($contenu,$idUser)){
            http_response_code(201);
            $response['message'] = 'GOOD ENTRY';
        }else{
            http_response_code(400);
            $response['message'] = 'BAD ENTRY';
        }
    }else{
        http_response_code(400);
        $response['message'] = 'INCOMPREHENSIBLE DATA';
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    http_response_code(405);
    $response['error_code'] = 405;
    $response['message'] = 'BAD REQUEST TYPE';
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There is no post body

> i'm putting this url directly in postman, and press send.

I don't use postman myself, but doing this will generate a post request with no data it's the equivalent of:

```
curl -X POST http://example.com
```

That's not passing a post body at all. The intent is more like:

```
curl http://example.com
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"contenu":"Hello","idUser":4}'
```

This is why `file_get_contents("php://input")` doesn't return anything.

Note that html form data is available via [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) - but only for urlencoded POST bodies (which I understand not to be the intent of the question).

### Where is the data?

> i'm putting this url directly in postman, and press send.

Returning to this quote, the only place for the data is in the url - that is *not* the normal way to pass data with a post request.

Url arguments are available via [$_GET](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php), with the url in the question this code:

```php
<?php
var_dump($_GET);
```

will output:

```
array(2) {
  ["contenu"]=>
  string(7) "'Hello'"
  ["idUser"]=>
  string(1) "4"
}
```

A detail, but note the string includes the single quotes which are in the url (that are probably not desired).

### What's the right way to do this?

With a request being made like this:

```
curl http://example.com
   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
   -d '{"contenu":"Hello","idUser":4}'
```

That data can be accessed like so:

```php
<?php
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($body, true);
$jsonError = json_last_error();
if ($jsonError) {
  print_r(['input' => $body, 'error' => json_last_error_msg()]);
  exit;
}

echo $data['contenu']; // Hello
echo $data['idUser'];  // 4
...
```

This is very similar to the code in the question, the error appears to primarily be *how* the request is being made rather than the php logic.